# How do I update the legend labels in a time series chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to add a label to the geom_line() lines to update the series label in the legend?

Instead of the legend showing the hex colour code, I would like it to show
#eb6b63 -> Revenue
#407edb -> Profit

```
ggplot(RevGroup, aes(x=MonthYear)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=sum_rev_month, color = '#eb6b63'))+
  geom_line(aes(y=sum_prof_month, color = '#407edb')) +
  myTheme+
  labs(colour = "Amount($)", title = 'Yearly Revenue and Profit trends', x = 'Year', y = 'Amount($)')
```

The above code produces the below plot.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `scale_color_manual`:

```
ggplot(RevGroup, aes(x=MonthYear)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=sum_rev_month, color = "Revenue"))+
  geom_line(aes(y=sum_prof_month, color = "Profit")) +
  myTheme +
  labs(colour = "Amount($)", title = 'Yearly Revenue and Profit trends', x = 'Year', y = 'Amount($)') +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('#eb6b63', '#407edb'))
```

Usually it is preferable to reshape your data into a long format so you can set the `color` aesthetic with a variable rather than manually.